# Implementing a recursive lock

Tags: javascript, typescript, async-await

I have created a Synchronizable mixin, which provides `synchronized` function:

```
const lock = Symbol('Synchronizable lock');
const queue = Symbol('Synchronizable queue');

export class Synchronizable {
  private [lock] = false;
  private [queue]: Array<() => void> = [];

  public async synchronized<T>(fn: () => Promise<T>): Promise<T> {
    while (true) {
      if (this[lock]) await new Promise(resolve => this[queue].push(resolve));
      else {
        this[lock] = true;
        try {
          return await fn();
        } finally {
          this[lock] = false;
          const tmp = this[queue];
          this[queue] = [];
          tmp.forEach(e => e());
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

But the lock is not recursive, locking the object when locked will cause dead lock:

```
const c = new Synchronizable();
await c.synchronized(() => c.synchronized(async () => void 0));
```

### How to implement recursive lock ?

The full code is upload to [github](https://github.com/kghost/synchronized-object) with testcases

#### First thought

Just like any other language, save current thread-id when lock then compare the saved thread-id with current thread-id, if match proceed.

But javascript doesn't provide thread-id, and defer a closure doesn't generate a new id.

#### Second thought

track the call stack, find any other lock call inside stack, check if it is the same lock.

The problem is that stack trace may not follow callback, like `setTimeout`, so it won't be able to detect a lock before the callback.

Comment: @Rajesh you can try the test cases, it is definitely needed. The test cases also demonstrate use cases.

Comment: @ZangMingJie why do you need locks in single-threaded environment?

Comment: @Dmitry see test cases, these test cases also demonstrate use cases.

Comment: @ZangMingJie, you dont need locks in single threaded environment. From wikipedia, In computer science, a lock or mutex (from mutual exclusion) is a synchronization mechanism for enforcing limits on access to a resource in an environment where there are many **threads of execution**. A lock is designed to enforce a mutual exclusion concurrency control policy.

Comment: @nrgwsth http://www.talkinghightech.com/en/creating-a-js-lock-for-a-resource/ Hope this article helps you understand why synchronize operator is needed in javascript.

Comment: So what do you expect to happen in the recursive case? An exception?

Answer (score -1):

I found it is possible to achieve with Zone.js using first approach, where Zone.js provides a way to define thread-local variable.